# How to make cardview show only bottom shadow

Tags: android

i use following code:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
        app:cardElevation="4dp">
    <TextView android:text="in card view" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

the screenshot is:

[image]

how to make only bottom show shadow?

Comment: Would be nice to control shadows, also looking for the same answer

Comment: remove this line  app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"

Comment: @Benjamin, what will it change?

Answer (score 5):

If you want a linear shadow, try this:

```
<View
    android:id="@+id/shadow"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="3dp"
    android:background="@drawable/down_shadow"
    />
```

down_shadow.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle"
    >

    <gradient
        android:angle="-90"
        android:endColor="#EEEEEE"
        android:startColor="#FFFFFF"
        />

</shape>
```

See also different articles for manual setting of shadows like this: https://medium.com/@ArmanSo/take-control-of-views-shadow-android-c6b35ba573e9.